# GIMP is messing up my GIF color index

Tags: gimp, gif

I'm modifying an existing animated GIF using GIMP. For some reason, GIMP opens it as an RGB file.

But after doing a color analysis it told me there are only 255 colours. That's just right!

However, when I do turn on indexed mode, it generates a new palette which degrades the image.

Even with all the blending/dithering options turned on or off, it applies a new 255 colour palette that is different from the 255 colours that are actually there.

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: The question is why your Gimp opens the GIF as RGB - it opens and keeps them indexed here on Gimp 2.8.2.

Comment: The only setting I found to possibly convert an indexed file to RGB is in Color Management preferences - File Open behaviour. However whatever I tell it to do there it alway opens my GIFs indexed. Do you use CM profiles?

Answer (score 2):

To keep the GIMP imported palette in order, uncheck the "[X] Remove unused colors from colormap" checkbox when you're converting the image mode to indexed.

It only took me 4 years to figure this out :D